# Toggling "experimental" for Play 2.1/sbt

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.1

I need to use Akka 2.1 for my Play 2.1-snapshot (because 2.1 has been converted to scala.concurrent.Future instead of the old Future from Akka, I figured that I will need to use akka.pattern.Patterns.ask from Akka 2.1 instead). However, the Play 2.1-snapshot is configured to use 2.0.2 by default:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor:2.0.2                                | com.github.scala-incubator.io:scala-io-core_2.9.2:0.4.1 | As akka-actor-2.0.2.jar                     |
|                                                                   | com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j:2.0.2                      |                                             |
|                                                                   | play:play_2.9.2:2.1-SNAPSHOT                            |                                             |
|                                                                   | play:akka-sip14-adapters_2.9.2:2.1-SNAPSHOT             |                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

And in Play/project/Build.scala

```
"com.typesafe.akka"                 %    (if(experimental) "akka-   actor_2.10.0-M7" else "akka-actor" ) % (if(experimental) "2.1-M2" else "2.0.2"),
"com.typesafe.akka"                 %    (if(experimental) "akka-   slf4j_2.10.0-M7" else "akka-slf4j" ) % (if(experimental) "2.1-M2" else "2.0.2"),
```

How do I turn on experimental for Play 2.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a Play snapshot yourself, and use the `experimental` system property set to true when starting sbt:

```
-Dexperimental=true
```

I found the info [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/project/Build.scala#L238).

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks
For others, the full command is
    cd $PLAY/framework
    ./build -Dexperimental=true